# undefined method `stringify_keys' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

Gives me that error with this code

```
module Spree::Admin::ProductsHelper
  def stores_checkbox
    capture do
      Spree::Store.all.each do |store| 
        concat hidden_field_tag "product[store_ids][]", store.id, @product.stores.include?(store)
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

But it was ok with this one....

```
module Spree::Admin::ProductsHelper
  def stores_checkbox
    capture do
      Spree::Store.all.each do |store| 
        concat check_box_tag "product[store_ids][]", store.id, @product.stores.include?(store), :style => "display: none;"
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

`hidden_field_tag "product[store_ids][]", store.id, @product.stores.include?(store)`

to:

`hidden_field_tag "product[store_ids][]", store.id`

The issue: `hidden_field_tag` is expecting a hash as it's last parameter, but you are passing in a `false` (boolean).

The change I suggest will add the product store_id as a hidden field on the form, with it's value set to `store.id`.

You can read more about the hidden_field_tag [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag).

Answer (score 0):

Your third parameter needs to be an options hash.  `check_box_tag` has a different method signature, where the third parameter is the initial checked state, and the options hash is the fourth parameter.  Whenever you see that `stringify_keys` error, your first guess should be that a hash was expected, and you provided something else.  Just get rid of your third parameter, and it should work fine.